# CountVectorizer fit-transform() not working for custom token_pattern

Tags: python, scikit-learn, countvectorizer

I need to use CountVectorizer on text that contains names of programming languages like 'R','C' etc . But CountVectorizer discards "words" that contain only one character.

```
    cv1 = CountVectorizer(min_df=2, stop_words='english')
    tokenize = cv1.build_tokenizer()
    tokenize("Python, Time Series, Cloud, Data Modeling, R")
```

Output:

Out[172]:
['Python', 'Time', 'Series', 'Cloud', 'Data', 'Modeling']

I then tweak the 'token_pattern' so that it considers 'R' also as a token.

```
    cv1 = CountVectorizer(min_df=1, stop_words='english', token_pattern=r'(?u)\b\w\w+\b|R|C' ,tokenizer=None)
    tokenize = cv1.build_tokenizer()
    tokenize("Python, Time Series, Cloud, R ,Data Modeling")
```

Output :
Out[187]:
['Python', 'Time', 'Series', 'Cloud', 'R', 'Data', 'Modeling']

But ,

```
    cvmatrix1 = cv1.fit_transform(["Python, Time Series, Cloud, R ,Data Modeling"])
    cv1.vocabulary_
```

Gives the output :

Out[189]:
{'cloud': 0, 'data': 1, 'modeling': 2, 'python': 3, 'series': 4, 'time': 5}

Why is this happening?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that *R* is dropped is that the regex captures the capital letter *R*, where the actual input of the tokenizer will be in lower case. The reason behind that is that the [`pre-processor`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.build_preprocessor) call the `.lower()` function on the original string before tokenizing it:

```
tokenize = cv1.build_tokenizer()
preprocess = cv1.build_preprocessor()
tokenize(preprocess("Python, Time Series, Cloud, R ,Data Modeling"))
```

Yields:

```
['python', 'time', 'series', 'cloud', 'data', 'modeling']
```